# Nginx request not timing out

Tags: nginx

I am very new to Nginx. I have set up a Nginx in my Live environment.

**Problem Statement**
I have set 4 servers as upstream servers in my Nginx configuration. I could see there are few requests which take more than 180 seconds overall and that makes my system very slow. I could see few requests going to the first server in the upstream and then selecting the 2nd server in the upstream. So i guess, the problem could be the first server is timing out and sending back the response after some timeout period. The only timeout period set in my configuration is

```
proxy_read_timeout 180;
```

Is this the main culprit? Can I get the timeout from the server if I change this value to a lesser value?

I need to change the value in the Live only after some expert advice.

Please someone put some light into this query.